# Seaborn hue with loc condition

Tags: pandas, conditional-statements, seaborn, hue

I'm facing the following problem: I'd like to create a lmplot with seaborn and I'd like to distinguish the colors not based on an existing column but **based on a condition** adressed to a column.

Given the following df for a rental price prediction:

| area | rental price | year build | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 40 | 400 | 1990 | ... |
| 60 | 840 | 1995 | ... |
| 480 | 16 | 1997 | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

```
sns.lmplot(x="area", y="rental price", data=df, hue = df.loc[df['year build'] > 1992])
```

this one above is not working. I know I can add a column representing this condition and adressing this column in "hue" but is there no way giving seaborn a condition to hue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a new column with the boolean information and use that for the hue. For example `data['at least from eighties'] = data['model_year'] >= 80`. This will create a legend with the column name as title, and `False` and `True` as texts.  If you map the values to strings, these will appear.  Here is an example using one of seaborn's demo datasets:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = sns.load_dataset('mpg')
df['decenium'] = (df['model_year'] >= 80).map({False: "seventies", True: "eighties"})

sns.lmplot(x='weight', y='mpg', data=df, hue='decenium')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.lmplot with hue over a condition]